# matching very long and complex version numbers with regular expressions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have lots of lines like this.

```
some text some more text v3.1.0-beta.4 more & more text
some text some v2 build.3 some more text more & more text
some text some v21.1.23456.551436a4 alpha.4 some more text v16.1.2 more & more text
```

version numbers are:

```
v3.1.0-beta.4
v2 build 3
v21.1.23456.551436a4 alpha.4 and v16.1.2
```

The problem is I can have have words beta or build or neither in my version numbers. variable length of version numbers.

Here's what I have now and this can only match numbers.

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

How do I search for the existence of one or more version numbers in a give line like shown in above lines like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
\bv[\d+]+[\w.]*(?:[-\s]+(?:alpha|beta|build)[\w.]*)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sualem/3/)

**Pattern Details:**

- `\bv`: Match `v` after a word boundary
- `[\d+]+`: Match 1+ digit or dot characters
- `[\w.]*`: Match 0 or more word or dot characters
- `(?:[-\s]+(?:alpha|beta|build)[\w.]*)?`: starting with whitespace or hyphen, optionally match `alpha|beta|build` part followed by 0 or more word or dot characters